# Python Correlation Matrix - Only Want columns that have absolute value more than .5

Tags: python, correlation

I have 41 variables and most of them are not correlated at all. I would only like to include just a few of the columns to illustrate the more highly correlated or more highly negatively correlated columns. Try as I might, I can't seem to get this to work even though I've looked at numerous articles and questions. Thank you.

df.columns

Index(['ResponseId', 'Consent', 'AgeQualifier', 'Team', 'TeamOther',
'FanStrength', 'WinImportance', 'Emotion', 'Happiness', 'Satisfaction',
'Passion', 'ViewershipHomeGame', 'ViewershipRoadGame',
'ViewershipTVCable', 'ViewershipStreaming', 'ViewershipRestaurantBar',
'NameChangeViewershipHomeGame', 'NameChangeViewershipRoadGame',
'NameChangeViewershipTVCable', 'NameChangeViewershipStreaming',
'NameChangeViewershipRestaurantBar', 'Purchased', 'Purchased_Jersey_1',
'Purchased_Clothing_2', 'Purchased_Memorabilia_3', 'Purchased_Office_4',
'Purchased_Equipment_5', 'PurchaseIntentionNameChangeJersey',
'PurchaseIntentionNameChangeClothing',
'PurchaseIntentionNameChangeMemorabilia',
'PurchaseIntentionNameChangeHomeOffice',
'PurchaseIntentionNameChangeEquipment', 'Support_SeasonTickets',
'Support_Donations ', 'Support_Volunteer ',
'SupportNameChangeSeasonTickets', 'SupportNameChangeDonateMoney',
'SupportNameChangeVolunteer', 'State', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Ethnicity',
'EthnicityOther', 'Income', 'Drawing', 'Email'],
dtype='object')

correlation_matrix = df.corr().round(2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50,50))
sns.heatmap(data=correlation_matrix,cmap = 'rainbow' , annot=True, ax=ax)

Thoughts?

Comment: can you post an example of what you want to achieve?
because it is possible that two columns are highly correlated but there is a column which is correlated to many other columns such that value in correlation matrix>0.5, and many other scenarios

Comment: Here is a small part of the matrix.  I want columns that have > .50.                                   Consent AgeQualifier Team FanStrength WinImportance Emotion Happiness Satisfaction Passion ViewershipHomeGame
Consent NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
AgeQualifier NaN 1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Team NaN NaN 1 0.02 0.02 0.02 -0.03 0.01 0
FanStrength NaN NaN 0.02 1 0.69 0.39 0.41 0.3 0.32
WinImportance NaN NaN 0.02 0.69 1 0.44 0.44 0.34 0.37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleaned matrix would be

|  | Consent | AgeQualifier | Team | FanStrength | WinImportance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Consent | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| AgeQualifier | NaN | 1.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Team | NaN | NaN | 1.00 | 0.02 | 0.02 |
| FanStrength | NaN | NaN | 0.02 | 1.00 | 0.69 |
| WinImportance | NaN | NaN | 0.02 | 0.69 | 1.00 |

To solve this you need to select any matrix value non diagonal and absolute value >0.5

```
temp = df[(df>0.5)&(df!=1)].abs().max()
print(temp[~temp.isna()])
```

This would yield column names which have at least one correlation in correlation matrix>0.5

This yields

```
FanStrength      0.69
WinImportance    0.69
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Bless You! That is great.